# how to render html content with literal control of specific height and width

Tags: html, asp.net-4.0

I have one page with name Template Management for listing all available html templates. Now i have problem with setting my literal control with specific height and width.

[image]

Here is my page source for general idea on how i set this html content to literal control :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="thumb" align="center" style="height:150px;width:130px">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TemplateBody")%>'></asp:Literal>
<ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme1" runat="Server" 
TargetControlID="Literal4" 
PopupControlID="Panel2" 
DynamicContextKey='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
DynamicControlID="Panel2"
DynamicServiceMethod="GetDynamicContent" 
PopupPosition="Right" 
OffsetX="-25" 
OffsetY="15"/>
</td>
</table>
</div>
<table width="50%" align="left" style="border-color:Black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelect" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"/></td>
<td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="quicklink" 
Text='<%# Eval("TemplateName") %>' CommandName="ViewTemplate" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
<br/>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="normaltext" 
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CreatedDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' 
ToolTip='<%# Bind("CreatedDate","{0:F}") %>'></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Can someone please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: i was put my Literal control in Panel control and apply fix height and width. but i have no success. i googled up and find that put literal control in div with height and width. but panel control also renderd as div. what was the solution to fix this issue. please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use iframes and set all content with fixed height and width. here use srcdoc not supported with ie but all browser shows it's content with fixed heigth and width.